# Jenkins - Selecting SSH Host at Run time

Tags: jenkins, ssh, host, scp

I have to mention the SSH host or SCP host while configuring the Job.

Is there any option by which we can select the host name in Run-time?
Just like we can select the Node name in which we want the script or shell commands to be executed, using Node Plugin

To be specific - 
I am passing few files to a Host, it can either be DEV, QA, or PROD and then based on that a set of commands will be executed in that particular Host.
As set of commands/script is generic, only the Host changes, so I need to develop one single job and pass the Host name in the Run-time where the file will be placed.
Is there any way out ?
Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Is there any way out ?` It looks like you need write custom `Build step` and perform all operations in script.

Comment: How can I write custom Build Step ? Could you please elaborate a bit. Any links or reference will be of great help.

Comment: I hope you are using Linux host for Jenkins CI. If I'm right, you can add `bash` build step and perform ssh copy through `bash`.